# TLS version supported by log4j2 Syslog Appender

Tags: log4j2

I have a Syslog Appender which communicates to server on tcp with below configuration. Configured an rsyslog server which is successfully receiving the messages from client. I'm new to this log4j2 and please excuse me if I missed something obvious.

```
  <Syslog name="Connector" format="RFC5424" host="10.10.10.10" port="5822" protocol="TCP" appName="Connector" includeMDC="true" mdcId="mdc" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true" immediateFlush="true" messageId="Audit" id="App" facility="local0">
      <SSL>
        <TrustStore location="truststore.p12" password="pJAY3nVuG?"/>
      </SSL>
    </Syslog>
```

I'm unable to find from documentation etc. on supported TLS versions for this. What's the minimum version it supports and if there is a way we can configure it to use only TLS 1.2+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log4j doesn't support any particular version of TLS. It uses a standard Java SSLSocket. So the version of TLS that is supported is controlled by how you configure the JVM. You need to check the relevant documentation, but the default is TLS 1.2 for Java 8 and 11.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for.